# Getting empty test suite when running with pytest from pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

I'm having issues with running pytest tests from inside PyCharm

I have a file x_tests.py inside a folder called agents_automation_2 in C:\Temp, the content of the file is

```
import pytest
def test_mytest():
    assert  False
```

When I run I get the following output

*C:\Python36-32\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2017.3.2\helpers\pycharm_jb_pytest_runner.py" --path C:/Temp/agents_automation_2
Launching py.test with arguments C:/Temp/agents_automation_2 in C:\Temp\agents_automation_2
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.4.2, py-1.5.2, pluggy-0.6.0
rootdir: C:\Temp\agents_automation_2, inifile:
plugins: xdist-1.22.0, forked-0.2
collected 0 items
======================== no tests ran in 0.01 seconds =========================*

However, when I run from a regular windows command line inside the folder the test runs OK

Any idea of what might be the issue ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: I got same error and figured out the definition name doesn't have "test_", so correct that.

Example : 
Before error :
class TestExample2 :

    def editProfile(self, dataLoad):
        print(dataLoad)
        print(dataLoad[1])

after fix :
class TestExample2 :

    def test_editProfile(self, dataLoad):
        print(dataLoad)
        print(dataLoad[1])

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The name of your test file does not conform to a default pytest discovery rules. If you change *x_tests.py* to *x_test.py* it run the test and fails as expected. Take a look at [this page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) for more info on pytest discovery rules.

Comment: In addition, It could be either test_*.py or *_test.py in filenames to be tested. Both conventions are correct.  Also, two points for the test functions i.e 

   1.  test prefixed test functions or methods outside of class

   2.  test prefixed test functions or methods inside Test prefixed test classes (without an __init__ method)

Comment: @Belerafon 
in addition to generic , it could've been better with example.
I got same error and figured out the definition name doesn't have "test_", so correct that.

Example : 
Before error :
class TestExample2 :

    def editProfile(self, dataLoad):
        print(dataLoad)
        print(dataLoad[1])

after fix :
class TestExample2 :

    def test_editProfile(self, dataLoad):
        print(dataLoad)
        print(dataLoad[1])

Answer (score 5):

In my case, test class contains **init** method, cause empty suite as well. What you need to do is to avoid to write init method.

Comment: Could you re-write/edit your answer for clarity?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that PyCharm is configured to use PyTest. By default it uses unittests. Checkout this doc: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/choosing-your-testing-framework.html. Once you've correctly configured PyCharm to use PyTest, when you, for example, open the context menu for the test file, you'll see something like **Run 'PyTest in ... '**

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had only to delete the `pytest.ini` file from the project.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure your conftest.py file is in same folder.
2. If you are using fixtures. Add "Test" keyword in class name (example = TestClass)

```py
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("setup1")

class TestClass:
      def test_abc(self):
          print("testcase execution")
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using WSL, problem might be related to WSL being unaccessible.
If you are getting this error on WSL,

`Logon failure: the user has not been granted the requested logon type at this computer.`

Try restarting the `vmcompute` service in PowerShell (run as Administrator):

```
powershell restart-service vmcompute
```

Source: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/5401

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had only change the class name with test in starting and that resolved my issue.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and figured out the definition name doesn't have "test_",

Example :
Before error :
class TestExample2 :

```
def editProfile(self, dataLoad):
    print(dataLoad)
    print(dataLoad[1])
```

after fix :
class TestExample2 :

```
def test_editProfile(self, dataLoad):
    print(dataLoad)
    print(dataLoad[1])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was caused by a circular import in a super class of my test. When I tried to run this super class (which has no tests itself) directly I saw the error message.